# Insert characters with accentuation in inputText

Tags: qml, translation, qqmlcomponent, qqmlapplicationengine

I need to insert characters with accent like É, ã or â when my app works in portuguese but when I try to insert (e.g. " a + ~") it doesn't happen.

The problem is caused because I'm using Qt Virtual Keyboard but I don't know how to avoid it.

Code example:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.VirtualKeyboard 2.15
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0

Window {
    id: window
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Column {
        id: cls
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 10
        spacing: 3

        Rectangle {
            id: frame
            width: parent.width
            height: 25
            border.color: green
            border.width: 1

            TextInput {
                id: txtInput
                anchors.fill: parent
                anchors.margins: 4
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It could be that the font you're using doesn't contain those characters.

Comment: I think no, because if I copy and paste "é" for example, the letter appears